# Как огрничить ip route по интерфейсу?

Tags: linux, сеть, wireguard

У меня есть wireguard и сеть на eth0. я хочу, чтобы весь трафик ТОЛЬКО с eth0 был пропущен через wg0.
Но `wg-quick` мне впиливает `ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0`.
Есть ли какой-то хак, чтобы `ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0` работал ТОЛЬКО на `eth0`?
Сейчас оно работает, но проводит весь трафик и текущей машины (если в консоле сделать `curl google.com`) и с `eth0` (если зайти в гугл с ноута, который подключен по проводу)

интернет получаю из `wlan0`
подсеть eth0 `192.10.0.1/24`
подсеть wg0 `192.11.0.1/24`

PS `169.254.0.0/16` от дефолтного конфига `eth0`. не стал удалять, чтобы было на что откатиться.

Общая инфа по сети:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000
192.10.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.10.0.1 metric 2048
192.11.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.11.0.2
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.104 metric 600

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 81:81:81:81:81:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.10.0.1/24 brd 192.10.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::81:cbff:fe3f:3e78/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:12:12:12:12:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.104/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 7228sec preferred_lft 7228sec
    inet6 fe80::5999:c242:35b3:d9f/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 192.11.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс в новую табличку:

```
ip rule add iif eth0 table 100
ip route add  0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 100
```